# MS Access - Disable textbox on continuous form based on combobox

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007, conditional-formatting

I'm using continuous forms in Access 2007 and I need to disable a bound textbox based on a combobox value. I tried using CASE statement in VBA but it disables the textbox for all rows.

I tried to add conditional formatting on the textbox based on combobox expression but it works only on form load. When I change the value on the combobox the conditional formatting does not work.

Is there a way,preferably using VBA,to enable/disable the record of each row based on row combobox selection?

Thank you.

Comment: Conditional formatting is the *only* way to achieve this. Is the formatting not applied after you leave the combobox? Or perhaps after a Refresh or Requery?

Comment: I added a refresh on combo_change and works, thank you.